# C# & SQL Server: how to open a form based on login

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms, authentication

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=STRONGLION;Initial Catalog=GIP;Integrated Security=True");

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select count(*) from tblLogin where Gebruikersnaam = '" + txtGebruikersnaam.Text + "' and Paswoord = '" + txtPaswoord.Text + "' and Accounttype'"  + "'", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (Accounttype == "1")
    {
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                this.Hide();
                FormAdmin ss = new FormAdmin();
                ss.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
    }
    else if (Accounttype == "0")
    {
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                this.Hide();
                FormWerknemer ss = new FormWerknemer();
                ss.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
    }
}
```

I have a login form that reads data from a database. What I want is that I can open a form based on what type of user logs in. Above you see a general example how I want it to work.

For example in the database I have 3 things username, password and accounttype, if account type is 1 then its an admin type of account if its 0 then its just a normal account.

Hope someone can help out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to build sql texts, use parameters

Comment: list of things to Fix: SQL Injection, don't store plain text passwords (and use a salt)

Comment: I know its wrong but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is wrong, the last part of your WHERE statement is meaningless

```
"' and Accounttype'"  + "'", con);
```

where is the value for the field Accounttype?

However there is a bigger problem here and is the string concatenation to build your sql text. This could be used to create an Sql Injection attack or it could be simply a source of bugs if your input values cannot be correctly parsed.

You could use a parameterized query as this one

```
string cmdText = @"Select count(*) 
                   from tblLogin 
                   where Gebruikersnaam = @name and
                         Paswoord = @pwd and 
                         Accounttype = @type";
```

and there is no need to build an SqlDataAdapter and a DataTable if you want to get a simple scalar value from your data (the count)

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con))
{
   con.Open();
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtGebruikersnaam.Text;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@pwd", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPaswoord.Text;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Accounttype;
   int countType = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

   if(countType == 0)
      MessageBox.Show("No user found for the type requested");
   else
   {
       if (Accounttype == "1")
       {
            this.Hide();
            FormAdmin ss = new FormAdmin();
            ss.Show();
       }
       else if (Accounttype == "0")
       {
            this.Hide();
            FormWerknemer ss = new FormWerknemer();
            ss.Show();
        }
    }

}
```

Consider also the advice given in the comments above. You should not store passwords in plain text inside the database. This is a big security risk because everyone that could look at your table could see the password of your users.